# Issue with running a gradle project on android

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I am trying to run a project that I found on github, This is the link to the  [project](https://github.com/p-acs/ethereum-android-lib). I tried to put it in android studio, Unfortunately I cant create a configuration to run for that project. Its a library project. How can I install it. There is no modules appearing for this project. This is the gradle file

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.12.0'
    classpath "gradle.plugin.nl.javadude.gradle.plugins:license-gradle-plugin:0.12.1"
   }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
    }
}

}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: "com.github.hierynomus.license"


license {
   license {
    header = file('HEADER.txt')
    skipExistingHeaders = true
    ignoreFailures = false
}
}

   android {

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 15
    versionCode Integer.parseInt(project.VERSION_CODE)
    versionName project.VERSION_NAME
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}

  lintOptions {
       disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
 }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.1-1'
    }

def isReleaseBuild() {
    return project.VERSION_NAME.contains("SNAPSHOT") == false
   }


   apply from: './maven_push.gradle'
```

Comment: Hey , This is a lib project without demo thats why you cannot run it . You can only inherit it in your project .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is a library you can only run with a app that you are developing and not run it as stand alone.